# Upgrading core protocol version (docker quickstart, standalone)

Tags: stellar-core, protocol

I built the [v10 docker image](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon/blob/master/Dockerfile.testing) and launched it exposing the HTTP port for core.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.testing -t stellar:v10 .
docker run --rm -it -p "5432:5432" -p "8000:8000" -p "11626:11626" \
    --name stellar stellar:v10 --standalone
```

At launch, the protocol version is 0.

I then attempted to update the protocol.

```
curl "http://localhost:11626/upgrades?mode=set&protocolversion=10&upgradetime=2018-08-18T00:00:00Z"
```

The `upgrades` endpoint now reports v10.

```
curl http://localhost:11626/upgrades?mode=get
{
    "time": 1534550400,
    "version": {
        "has": true,
        "val": 10
    },
    "fee": {
        "has": false
    },
    "maxtxsize": {
        "has": false
    },
    "reserve": {
        "has": false
    }
}
```

But the most recent ledger does not:

```
curl -s "http://localhost:8000/ledgers?cursor=now&limit=1&order=desc" \
    | jq '._embedded.records[0].protocol_version'
0
```

The system in this state does not support any non v0 operation (after limited testing).

What are the additional steps to upgrading the protocol version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the date that you used is in the future `1534550400 = Saturday, August 18, 2018 12:00:00 AM`.

if you want it to happen right away, just use the epoch as per the documentation it's `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I changed it to one minute in the future as a test and it updated correctly at the right time.

Comment: Update to docs to clarify that param. https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/pull/1759